# How do I query an HID device as a non-superuser in Linux?

Tags: permissions, usb-device, hid

With superuser privileges, I send instructions to the device as follows:

```
$ sudo hid-query /dev/hidraw1 0x01 0x80 0x33 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Device /dev/hidraw1 : 413d:2107 interface 1 : (null) (null)

Writing data (9 bytes):
     00 01 80 33   01 00 00 00   00

Response from device (8 bytes):
     80 40 07 9b   11 4a 00 00
```

As an ordinary user, I can run hid-query but no devices are found:

```
$ hid-query /dev/hidraw1 0x01 0x80 0x33 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
No HID devices were found.
```

There are already rw permissions on the device path:

```
$ ls -la /dev/hidraw1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 244, 1 Nov  7 16:52 /dev/hidraw1
```

Comment: If the `hid-query` command you're using is [this one](https://github.com/edorfaus/TEMPered/blob/master/utils/hid-query.c), it seems to have rather rudimentary error handling: whenever the `hidapi` library function `hid_enumerate()` returns NULL, it will output "No HID devices were found." instead of using `hid_error()` to get the actual error message from the `hidapi` library. So the actual error might be something different, or the `hid_enumerate()` function might requre access to *all* hidraw devices in order to complete successfully.

Comment: Also, there does not seem to be a way to avoid the `hid_enumerate()` step, as `hid-query` will always call it.

Comment: @telcoM Thank you, but the trouble persists even with rw permissions set for /dev/hidraw*.

Comment: Then it might be necessary to add a `hid_error()` call to `hid-query` in the appropriate location and print the message it returns so that `hid-query` will be able to report the actual reason for the error, or else the best anyone can do is blind guessing.